# Slutsky's theorem for random matrices

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, random-matrices

This image is from [Applied Multivariate Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387953477). In this image `plim`  means convergence in probability. I could not find the reference about the statement for random matrices. I'd highly appreciate if you cite the reference or give the proof. Thanks

[image: This]

Answer (score 1):

Random matrix is just a vector. Then you have joint distribution of $Y_n, X_n$ converges to $A,B$ where $A,B$ are independent. Continuous Mapping Theorem can be applied to conclude that for any continuous function $f(X_n,Y_n) \to f(X,Y)$.