# If a random matrix converges to an invertible constant matrix $A$, does its inverse converge to $inv(A)$?

Tags: matrices, inverse, probability-limit-theorems, random-matrices

Let $B_n$ be a sequence of random matrices and
$$
\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\text{plim}}(B_n) = A,
$$
with A invertible.
Does this imply that
$$
\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\text{plim}}(B_n^{-1}) = A^{-1}?
$$

Comment: Yes, the convergence in probability - and also the convergence in distribution - are preserved by composition with a map, provided the distribution of the limit gives probability 1 to the continuity set of the map. Here, the map is $M \mapsto M^{-1}$ on $GL_n(C)$, and you assume that $A$ is (almost surely) invertible.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Should not we also assume that the matrices $B_n$ be invertible here too?

Comment: The set of all invertible matrices is open and contains $A$ almost surely, so the probability that $B_n$ is invertible tends to $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity (consequence of Portmanteau's theorem for the convergence in distribution).

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Do you happen to know where I can find citeable reference for this result? If not, do you have a suggestion of keywords I could use to search for it?

Comment: Which result : $GL_n(R)$ open in $M_n(R)$? The stability of convergences (almost sure, in probability, in distribution) by composition with functions which are almost surely continuous with regard to the limit distribution? I do not know reference for that.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan No, I mean the result "If a random matrix converges to an invertible constant matrix A, its inverse converges to inv(A)." Using your reasoning to prove it would be too difficult for me and beyond the scope of the field I work in.

Comment: If $A$  is constant (you did not write that before), the reasoning gets simpler, you have just to use the definition of convergence in probability and the continuity at $A$ `forall $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$,...'

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thanks! I think I would manage to do that, but I also found a reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147084/slutskys-theorem-for-random-matrices